# Require caller to enter either parameter A OR B for method - but not both

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method with 3 parameters, A, B, C

```
public MyObj SelectStuff(int A, string B, bool C)
{
...
}
```

I want callers to be forced to enter EITHER A or B, but not both or neither - and always C. Using named parameters is preferable.

So this is OK

```
SelectStuff(A: 3, C: false)
```

This is OK

```
SelectStuff(B: "Hello", C: false)
```

This isn't

```
SelectStuff(A: 2, B: "Bye", C: true)
```

This isn't

```
SelectStuff(B: "hi")
```

I can find nothing on Google about this.

I would like one concise neat method with minimal code if possible. Is this possible?

Comment: Make two methods. One receives A,C the other B,C, make your method with A,B,C private and call it from the public twos

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the method with the three parameters making it *private* and then create two public methods with the signature for A or B (always with C).

These two public methods will call the internal method passing conventional values for the missing parameters in such a way that you can understand which of the two public methods has been called

```
public MyObj SelectStuff(int A, bool C)
{
    return SelectStuff(A, null, C);
}
public MyObj SelectStuff(string B, bool C)
{
    return SelectStuff(-1, B, C);
}
private MyObj SelectStuff(int A, string B, bool C)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(B))
    {
       // Called from the method with A,C
       ....
    }
    else
    {
       // Called from the method with B,C
       ....
    }
}
```

Of course this solution requires that there is no valid input for a null string as parameter B and no valid input for an integer A with value -1.

Answer (score 0):

there is no chance to restrict the parameters based on your preference.so,better to keep caller parameters as optional then call the caller with fields priority.